# Stream Binary data in Request Body in POST method in API

Tags: python, bigdata, fastapi

I have large data to transfer over an API and I get:

> Request Entity Too Large

Client:

```
 def write_data(self, table, data):
        response = None
        try:
            API_ENDPOINT = self.base_url+ "/write_data"
            API_KEY_VALUE =  self.api_key_value
            API_KEY =  self.api_key
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', API_KEY: API_KEY_VALUE}
            payload = {
                "table": table,
                "data": data,
            }
            response = requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, json=payload)
            response.raise_for_status()

            # Check the response status code and handle it as needed
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print("Request successful:" + API_ENDPOINT)
            else:
                print(f"Unexpected status code: {response.status_code}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Caught an exception: {e}")
            # print(payload)
            traceback.print_exc()
        if response is not None:
            return response.json()
        else:
            return None
```

FastAPI:

```
@parser_router.post("/write_data", tags=["Parser"], response_model=None)
async def write_data(
        table: TableNamesEnum = Body(..., description="table name", embeded=True),
        data=Body(..., description="table data", embeded=True),
        api_key: str = Security(get_api_key),
        session: Session = Depends(get_session)) -> None:
    """
        Insert data into table.

        :param session:
        :param api_key:
        :param table: (str) Table name
        :param data: (list dict) data to insert.
        """
    try:
        if table == TableNamesEnum.spectrum:
            print("spectrum table")
            i = 0
            for spectra in data:
                spectra["mz"] = base64.b64decode(spectra["mz"])
                spectra["intensity"] = base64.b64decode(spectra["intensity"])
                data[i] = spectra
                i += 1

        table = Table(table, meta, autoload_with=engine)
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            statement = table.insert().values(data)
            result = conn.execute(statement)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        return None

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Caught an exception: {e}")
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        session.close()
    return None
```

Error:

> Caught an exception: 413 Client Error: Request Entity Too Large for url:<URL here

Note: Ignore about parsing table name and not using ORM for the time being.

I do not want to touch the traffic manager to allow transferring huge data for that endpoint. Can I stream data(with header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`) in `POST` method in Request Body? I appreciate if anyone can give an example

Comment: What are the technologies involved? Which Python library is the server built with? Which Python library are you using as the client? Are you using native python modules such as urllib? [Even Python recommends the](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) [Requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: I used Python FastAPI to implement rest API

Comment: You should probably add the tag then.

Comment: In the simplest case, you should use [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#using-streamingresponse-with-file-like-objects)

Comment: Note that this is for POST method, not GET method streaming. We need this from client side, not from server side